# Type Mismatch in an If statement in a For Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a lot of trouble trying to figure out why the following code is giving me an `Error '13'`.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
Sub summary()
    Dim last As Variant
    lastrow = Sheet4.Range("g" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    c = 0
    For x = 2 To lastrow
        If Sheet4.Cells(x, 10) = Sheet4.Cells(x, 12) Then
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: My suggestion is to change `Sheet4` to `Sheets("Sheet4")`. If you want to refer to the sheet name which you see in your workbook ou should always use the latter option, as bare `Sheet4`is not the same.

Comment: you set the variable 'last' to the variant data type, but never end up using it. if you meant to use it to hold the lastrow variable, in addition to changing the variable names to match I would use the long data type instead of the variant data type which is slower and takes up more memory

Comment: @DyRuss - Maybe he uses it, as in the original code version there was no `End Sub`.

Answer (score 3):

Check one of your cells in Col 10 or Col 12. They have a formula error. `#NA`, `#DIV/0!` or something else and hence maybe that is the reason why you are getting the `Run Time Error 13 Type Mismatch Error`.

The best way to check which cell is it to find the value of `x` at the time of error.

Here is an example to replicate the problem

Put `=0/0` in cell `A1` and run this code.

[image]

**Edit** To find which row the problem may be in, try this simple thing.

```
Sub summary()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim c As Long, x As Long

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    With Sheet4
        lastrow = .Range("g" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        c = 0
        For x = 2 To lastrow
            If .Cells(x, 10) = .Cells(x, 12) Then
                c = c + 1
            End If
        Next x
    End With

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox "At the time of error the value of x is " & x
End Sub
```

Comment: To fix it the lazy way, just add: `On Error Resume Next` before `If .Cells(x, 10) = .Cells(x, 12) Then` and then add `On Error Goto 0` after `End If`

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to do :P if you want to halt execution and not finish counting, you can use your sub. If you want to write the error to a log or something and continue, you would want to add more code. If you don't really care at all if a cell is errored and just want the valid cells counted, it can be done by ignoring the error. So often people act like everyone on here is working on a huge group project. Most people are just trying to speed up a simple task.

Comment: @user1274820: Now your advice sounds good with all that explanation. But if you say to use OERN because you are feeling lazy then like I said it is a bad advice ;)

Comment: I understand the community wants to promote good coding practices, but sometimes it is frustrating when they devise really complex methods to "fix the issue" that doesn't actually fix the issue. In this example, the code still errors, but now it says which line the error occurred at (which the Debugger does automatically). It hasn't actually fixed anything, just pointed out what the problem is, which is something you would be able to figure out on your own using simply the debugger. An actual solution ignores a cell with an error and keeps counting. I know you have good intentions ;) js

Comment: For example, I would use OERN, but after I close it with Goto 0, I would say If `Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox("Cell " & x & " had an error value ... continuing...")` That way the code completes and doesn't just stop dead in its tracks. Of course, the message box is optional.

Comment: @user1274820: I am not disagreeing with rest of your comments. I just objected to your "Lazy Statement` ;)

Comment: No worries, the only reason I said "Lazy" was in the hopes that I would not be told that I was offering bad advice (backfire). I said it was the "Lazy way" because it's not considered the "Right way" by anyone on here and I was hoping to avoid this kind of discussion. :)

Comment: No worries :) @user1274820

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Sub summary()
Dim lastrow As Variant
dim c as integer
 lastrow = sheets("Sheet4").Range("g" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

c = 0

For x = 2 To lastrow

If sheets("Sheet4").Cells(x, 10) = sheets("Sheet4").Cells(x, 12) Then


c = c + 1

End If
Next x
end sub
```

Comment: There are more instances of `Sheet4`. You should consider changing all of the bare `Sheet4` to `Sheets("Sheet4")`, not only the first one.

Comment: Sheet4 wasn't causing the `Run Time Error 13 Type Mismatch Error` :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - you're always one step ahead ;)

Comment: ye well he s a vba veteran